# SSIS - "Access to the path '\\XXX\data2\TXX\zz\Tracker - xx.xlsx' is denied."

Tags: permissions, ssis, files

SSIS error:

Recently the following error "Access to the path '\XXX\data2\TXX\zz\Tracker - xx.xlsx' is denied.". i occurring.

The SSIS package is executed through SQL Agent using a Domain service account and running as a job for years

No changes to SQL Server no changes to the fileserver permissions etc.

1st thing checked is the path - and the availability - the path is open to everyone not just the DW admin service account.

No changes have been made to the path according to IT team.

im stuck

Comment: if its a shared drive, can you add it as  network drive using the sql agent service account and see you are able to connect?